# Internet Explorer renders Select Boxes as Absolute?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Using a regular HTML select box :

```
<select>
    <option value="">click to select a task type</option>
    <option value="">Awesome Option</option>
```

When using this jQuery :

```
  $("select, option").live({
    mouseenter: function(){
      console.log("INSIDE");
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
      console.log("OUTSIDE");
    }
  });
```

When I click the select box, and mouse over any of the options, IE will respond with my mouse is "Outside".

Is there a work around for that?

Comment: Might not be relevant but `live` is replaced by `on`

Comment: Wouldn't the `blur` event work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens when you bind the event to just `option`. I don't think you can bind events to that. Or, if you can, not all events; `click` for sure and apparently these too.

The behavior makes sense as you really are moving your mouse outside of the `select` element when you move down to select an option. The browser/OS handles displaying the menu. And it's not just IE that does this. Chrome, too.

I would recommend using the `blur` event as it fires when the element loses focus. This will only fire when you click outside and close the menu.

```
 $("select").live({
    mouseenter: function(){
      console.log("INSIDE");
    },
    blur: function(){
      console.log("OUTSIDE");
    }
  });
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/icayes)